# Migrating of Web Apps on Azure from US Region to Indian Data Centers

Tags: azure-web-app-service

We have deployed our Web Apps on Azure. The sql Databases that they work on are located in South India.But the Web Apps are deployed in US Region. Please let us know how to migrate our Applications to Indian Data Center in Azure from US Data Centers .

Regards,
Susan Manoj Thankachan

Answer (score 0):

You can't change location of an app service plan. However, you could realize it with two ways.

1.You create a new service plan with the specific location and redeploy you web.

2.Still create a new service plan with the location you want, then go to the App Service you want to change, choose **Clone App**  under **Development Tools** ,in here you can rename web name and choose a new service plan. [Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9NzDF.png) is the screenshot.But if you want to use this function , you maybe need to scale up your original service plan, you could delete plan and web after clone your web.

If you still have questions, please let me know.

Comment: Thanks , got it, we may have to Clone

Comment: @Susan Manoj I'm glad it's helpful. If this could help you, could you accept my answer? Thanks.